# network render export - missing files

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, network

i'm using 4 servers in lan for an export with the Network Render Engine.

This is what the NetRender Monitor is saying. (done 504 done)
504 Done    30.8s   DESKTOP-MATRIXW10   view log    view result [show]

But in folder there is just frame n. 0 to 44
Where are the others frames?

When i download the .exr files they are black (in PS), but the thumbnails (in NetRender Monitor) show me the render files as they should be.

--
**What i did.**
I just uploaded the 44 files in pr for a quick preview, is that the problem? there is a way to fix it?